# How to exclude field in Orika bean mapper?

Tags: java, orika

I want to exclude some fields during mapping from a bean to `HashMap`.

Orika definition:

```
static {
        final MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
        mapperFactory.classMap(MyReq.class, Map.class)
                .exclude("myproperty")
                .byDefault()
                .register();
        MAPPER = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
    }
```

Bean definitions:

```
public class MyReq {
    private String myproperty;
}
```

Usage:

```
MyReq req = new MyReq;
Map map = MAPPER.map(req, Map.class);
```

Result: the `Map` **contains** the excluded `myproperty` field! Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also faced this problem, but only with `Map` instances (it works OK when class that you defined is destination object). However, there is a workaround, since Orika has multiple ways to define mapping rules, something like this:

```
mapperFactory.classMap(MyReq.class, Map.class)
                        .fieldMap("myproperty").exclude().add()
                        .byDefault()
                        .register();
```